# TDE in Oracle - Feature not enabled

Tags: oracle11g

I have standard edition of Oracle (version 11.2g) and I am trying to use TDE. I have successfully created a wallet but when I try and create a tablespace, I get

ORA-00439: feature not enabled: Transparent Data Encryption

Is this only enabled in enterprise edition? Assuming I have enterprise edition, does this feature come with extra costs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TDE requires the Advanced Security Option.  That is an extra cost option on top of the enterprise edition license.